# Kik Bot keyboard items not changing

Tags: javascript, node.js, kik

So I have a Kik bot that I am currently working on that uses the keyboards to suggest things that the user might want to say to the bot as most Kik bots do. For different users I want to have different options pop up. I created a function to check if the current user is once of those special users  and if so to display another option for them. I have conferment from many tests that the function is returning true, how ever the keyboard options refuse to change from what a normal user would see. Here is my code

```
message.stopTyping();
                  if (userIsAdmin(message.from)) //This function returns the boolean true
                  {
                  message.reply(Bot.Message.text("I don't understand what you are trying to ask me. Please reply with something I can work with.").addResponseKeyboard(["Homework", "Admin Options"]))
                  }
                  else
                  {
                  message.reply(Bot.Message.text("I don't understand what you are trying to ask me. Please reply with something I can work with.").addResponseKeyboard(["Homework"])) //The bot always displays this as the keyboard, no matter if the user is an admin or not
                  }
                  break;
                  }
```

Comment: Does your message actually get sent (= do you receive the message on the Kik app?).

Comment: @RémiVansteelandt Yeah, everything acts as it should except for the fact that the suggested keyboard doesn't change.

Comment: I would make the messages have different strings for testing purposes. I sounds like you are just always sending the second message. If you change the message bodies you'll be able to see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node Js likes to continue programs when functions start running so that it can take more requests. The function `userIsAdmin()` makes a web request to firebase so while taking only a fraction of a second to download the data, its long enough for it to return false before it was done. What I had to do was edit the function `userIsAdmin()` so that it took a callback as a parameter and then call it. Here is my new code:

```
let sendingMessage = Bot.Message.text("I don't understand what you are trying to ask me. Please reply with something I can work with.")

    adminCheck(user, function(isAdmin)
               {
               if (isAdmin)
               {
               bot.send(sendingMessage.addResponseKeyboard(adminSuggestedResponces), user)
               }
               else
               {
               bot.send(sendingMessage.addResponseKeyboard(userSuggestedResponces), user)
               }
               });
```

And here is my `adminCheck` function:

```
var isAdmin = false
    adminsRef.on("child_added", function(snapshot)
                 {
                 if(user == snapshot.key && snapshot.val() == true)
                 {
                 isAdmin = true
                 }
                 });

    adminsRef.once("value", function(snapshot)
                   {
                   callback(isAdmin)
                   });
```

Comment: Just to help you in case you encounter similar issues in the future, this has nothing to do with the execution time. Node.js works asynchronously most of the time, in order not to let the main thread just "hang". This way you can handle several requests in parallel. I would recommend checking out promises, which are a much cleaner way of dealing with that kind of things than simple callbacks.